# Making the whole document 12pt and non-bold including titles, toc, references etc

Tags: fonts, formatting

I am writing a thesis in social sciences and they don't have a template for the thesis (they use MS word). So, I am creating my own.

The whole thesis should be 12pt and there shouldn't be any bold characters. (italics are possible) So, I was wondering if there is a way to define everything that way, including chapters, table of contents, references, section names, title page, captions etc.

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** I am using `\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}`. If there is a better option, I can change it to another class. I didn't know margins are important, and I haven't actually dealt with them yet. But I guess 2cm margins will be fine.

I haven't decided what packages to load, but apacite, setspace, float, graphicx and times packages will most likely be used.

I was thinking, instead of defining everything as normalfont, there could be something like:

> Latex searches for bold font. Somehow it is directed to the normal
>   font. It thinks that it is bold, but it looks like normal font. And
>   the same thing for font size.

Comment: The `titlesec` package may be useful, the documentation of that package provides examples for most issues you mention in the question.

Comment: You're leaving a lot of design elements unspecified. E.g., which paper size is in use, and how wide are the margins. Which font (family) should be use? Which font sizes should be employed for chapter headers, for section headers, for subsection headers, etc? Is single-spacing, double-spacing, or some other spacing rule required? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I agree generally, but the question does specify font size for everything, so that bit is clear.

Comment: Can you provide an MWE showing the basics of your document? The best way to do what you want depends, for example, on your document class and any relevant packages you're loading. `\renewcommand\bfseries{m}` will do away with bold globally. (More accurately, it will make the bold series the same as the default medium series. Whether this is correct for what you need depends on the font you're using.)

Comment: @cfr - Aren't section and especially chapter headers typeset at a somewhat larger font size than the main body of the document? Let's see if the OP will provide additional information...

Comment: @Mico By default, yes. But the OP wants them in 12pt. At least, that's how I read the question.

Comment: Could you clarify if you want _all_ the text in your document to be 12pt (even the title)? I did not read it that way, but upon rereading your question, I am unsure.

Comment: @schtandard __Yes, everything__, even the title.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it using [KOMA-Script](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrartcl):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
    \patchcmd\@maketitle{\huge}{}{}{}
    \setkomafont{author}{}
    \setkomafont{date}{}
    \setkomafont{dedication}{}
    \setkomafont{publishers}{}
    \setkomafont{subject}{}
    \setkomafont{subtitle}{}
    \setkomafont{title}{}
    \setkomafont{titlehead}{}

    \setkomafont{disposition}{}
    \setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{}
    \setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
    \setkomafont{pagenumber}{}

    \renewcommand*\size@section{\normalsize}
    \renewcommand*\size@subsection{\normalsize}
    \renewcommand*\size@subsubsection{\normalsize}
    \renewcommand*\size@paragraph{\normalsize}
    \renewcommand*\size@subparagraph{\normalsize}
\makeatother

\title{A Title}
\author{An Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{A Section}
Nothing's bold.
Nothing's big.

\begin{description}
    \item[foo] bar
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image: The output of the code above]

- If you really want *everything* to be 12pt, I can't see you writing any documents so long that it would justify using chapters, so `scrartcl` (or `article`) is probably the better choice than `scrreprt` (or `report`).
- I removed the formatting (using `\setkomafont`) of everything I could think of that might be relevant here. If you find something that has some preset formatting, you can remove that analogously.
- I patched the `\huge`, that usually sets the title font size, out of `\@maketitle`. However, given your specific wishes, you probably want to redefine `\@maketitle` yourself anyway. You could get rid of that line then. (You can find the original definition of `\@maketitle` in `scrartcl.cls`, if you want to use it as a starting point.)

---

Some remarks on my part:

- I can't imagine why you would want to format your document this way. I recommend you think about it again, maybe after you finished writing its content, to see how different font sizes and weights can help the reader recognize headings and ease reading.
- If, for some reason, you really want to absolutely prevent the use of different font sizes and weights by any macro in your document, you could also just redefine the corresponding commands, e.g. `\let\bfseries\mdseris`, `\let\huge\normalsize`. This would however be quite literally "quick and dirty" and deprive you yourself of all those formatting possibilities. I recommend not doing this.

Comment: It's not so much that the OP doesn't want to use bold and different font sizes, it's that certain thesis commitees are very finicky about the way a thesis is presented (in this case, it feels as if they are just leaving the typewriter era)

Comment: Exactly as remco said. The thesis committee wants it that way. They do not want to see a single bold character and a different sized character. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If indeed the whole document has to be typeset in 12pt, you basically have to redefine all header styles. The font substitution trick others mentioned might get rid of the bold, but won't adjust font *sizes*.

There are probably several classes and packages that will help doing that. Personally I use the memoir class, where it's easy to do that kind of complete changes for headings of any level. For your case, an exemple would be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article,openany,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{*}{*}
%\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{*}{*}
%\checkandfixthelayout

\makechapterstyle{basefont}{%
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{Chapter~}
    \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
    \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter~---~}
    \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
    }

\setsecheadstyle{\normalfont}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\chapterstyle{basefont}    

\chapter{test 1}

\lipsum[1]

\section{a section}    

\lipsum[2]
\subsection{a subsection}  

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

It also includes the functionality of a number of other commonly used packages.

Comment: Please always include some code in your answer that shows how "easy" it is to change the document.